# Hibernate - NClob property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is my entity :

```
public class MyEntity {
   @javax.persistence.Lob
   java.sql.NClob prop;

   public void setProp(java.sql.NClob c) {
       prop=c;
   }

   public java.sql.NClob getProp() {
       return prop;
   }
}
```

When it's time to flush it to database, I get this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.NCLOB cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob 
 at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.getReplacement(BlobType.java:37) 
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.replace(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:359) 
 at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:212) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:600) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:337) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:464) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255) 
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84) 
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867) 
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851) 
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855) 
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:851)
```

Why does Hibernate try to cast it to java.sql.Blob ?
Can I specify another type instead of java.sql.Blob (java.sql.Clob) ?

**JDK 6**
**JPA 2**
**Hibernate 3.6.8.Final**
**Oracle 10.2g**
**Postgresql 8.3** (The entity is read from an Oracle database and then write to a Postgresql database)

I have opened a bug on this [on JIRA](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7035)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I solve my problem :

```
public class MyEntity {
   @Column(length=100000)
   String prop;

   public void setProp(String c) {
       prop=c;
   }

   public String getProp() {
       return prop;
   }
}
```

In my case the arbitrary value `100000` is really enough to handle the values the application will deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the String type instead of NClob, anyway you can try to replace the @Lob annotation with:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: This solution is gret but DB vendor specific.